# Change context language according to the current device language

Tags: java, android, locale, android-context

Alright i know it's okay to have many languages in a single app . But i couldnt find the proper way . So here is what i want to do as a start , i want the activity to detect the android device language and then change a simple text

```
 "@string/hello"
```

according to it . I know that the method is locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
but i dont know how to apply it . 
Secondly i want to give the user the option to change the language if he wants to .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
}
```

Here is the simple layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   

android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.vermelha.tourword.MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Tour Word</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

</resources>
```

values-tr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Tour Word</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="hello">Merhaba!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Ayralar</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: possible duplicated with [How to change language programatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new folder in res: values-es as example for Spanish, values-pt as example for Portuguese

Create a new strings.xml file

Put the same string there

values/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_about_title">About</string>
```

values-es/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_about_title">Acerca</string>
```

values-pt/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_about_title">Sobre</string>
```

Automatically when you use `@string/app_about_title` or via code `R.string.app_about_title` it will be translated
If you use a language that doesn't has the translation, it will use the standard (values fodler)

Comment: I did as you said . And i changed the locale in my device to tr but still showing the English one

Comment: did you create the new values folder? values-es and values-pt as example. Did you create the strings.xml inside this new folder?

Comment: Yes yes yes exactly as you said

Comment: edit your question and put your java code, layout.xml code and strings.xml code

Comment: Okay okay thanks it worked , i changed the hello world string name and it worked , it was all with that hello word ._. . Now can you please tell me about my other question ? Like if they want to change the language of the app manually ?